# How to check if the logic is sound and valid

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I am trying to figure out if a proposition is valid and sound. However I am tryign to figure out what the statement means and so far have been unable to find out anything.

It goes as follows:

p1 = It is windy

p2= The harddisk is flying through the air

p3= Eric wears a hat

so I am given the formula

p1, (p2 → p3) ∴ ¬p1

My question is, does this read as : "p1 *and* (if p2 then p3) therefore *not* p1"

and how would I show this on a truth table?

Comment: Exactly : you can show that the argument is *valid*, verify that $[p_1 \land (p_2 \to p_3)] \to \lnot p_1$ is a *tautology* (which is not).

Answer (score 0):

Some definitions regarding *propositional logic* :

> $\Gamma$ *tautologically implies* $\varphi$ (written $\Gamma \vDash \varphi$) iff every truth assignment for the sentence symbols in $\Gamma$ and $\varphi$ that satisfies every member of $\Gamma$ also satisfies $\varphi$.
>
> We say that $\varphi$ is a *tautology* (written $\vDash \varphi$), when $\emptyset \vDash \varphi$, i.e. every truth assignment (for the sentence symbols in $\varphi$) satisfies $\varphi$.

A basic result is :

> $\Gamma, α \vDash β$ iff $\Gamma \vDash (α \to β)$,

from which :

> $α \vDash β$ iff $\vDash (α \to β)$.

---

Now, we can apply these definition to the problem above, taking into account that an argument : "if $\alpha, \beta$, therefore $\varphi$ is *valid* when : $\alpha, \beta$ *tautologically implies* $\varphi$.

Thus, the problem ask to verify :

> if $p_1, (p_2 \to p_3) \vDash \lnot p_1$

and this, by what said above, is equivalent to ask :

> if $\vDash [p_1 \land (p_2 \to p_3)] \to \lnot p_1$.

In the case of a simple formula like this, the easisest way to verify if it is a *tautology* is to produce a truth-table.

Answer (score 0):

An argument is *valid* if the conclusion is a logical consequence of the premises.   That is, if it is logically impossible for both the premises to be true and yet the conclusion to be false.

An argument is *sound* if it is valid *and* the premises are justified.

In this case, the premises are $p_1$ and $(p_2\to p_3)$ and the conclusion is $\neg p_1$ .   Is it impossible for both premises to be true and yet the conclusion to be false?

> If $p$ is true, then $\neg p$ must be false, so it is certainly possible.   Thus the argument is not valid.